# semantical error when passing an array to the query

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

i have an array with conditions i have already prepared to pass it to the query:

array:

```
('u.registered = 1','u.active = 0', 'u.gender = M')
```

when i pass to the query, it works with the number comparison but not with the varchar which is M. The error appears in "gender", it says it is a semantical error. I assume is because i am not using expr()->literal('M'), but i can't do this because the query is "already built"..

Is there an alternative way so i don't have to code all over again?

this is the code:

```
public function customR($data){
    // var_dump($data);die();
    $this->qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $andX = $this->qb->expr()->andX();

    $this->qb->select('u')
    ->from('models\User','u');

    foreach ($data as $value){
        $andX->add($value);

            }

    $this->qb->add('where', $andX);


    $query = $this->qb->getQuery();
    // var_dump($query);die();
    $obj = $query->getResult();
    var_dump($obj);die();
            if (!empty($obj)){
        return $obj;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `already built`? You mean the `$data` variable just comes this way and you can't change it?

Comment: that's right. I "build" the condition in php and then just passes the array of string to the query. It's a simple solution but it's not working when i have to compare with a varchar, like "M" in this case

Comment: That is something you should handle when building the condition. After that, it will be already late and you'd have to parse the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I found no way to do this, so i just changed it a little bit.

I send an array with some elements, just to have the reference of what exists and what doesn't.

So, in my Data Service I've created a function and a snippet of that function to solutionate my question was to do this:

```
if($key == 'gender'){
    foreach($value as $key=>&$v){
    $condition = ('u.gender = '. $this->qb->expr()->literal($v));
    $orX->add($condition);
            }
        }
```